# Webscraping 1000's of links using Python concurrent.futures

Tags: python, web-scraping, concurrent.futures

I am trying to scrape data from about 1000's of links which have the same content and the same procedure to extract data. To speed up the process I am using the python's concurrent.futures, which I think is the best in terms of speed. When I scrape data from about 30 - 40 links as a trial, it works; but as the number increases it does not. Here is my code:

```
import re
import json
import requests
import concurrent.futures
import time

links_json = ['https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/backend/public/notification/view/id/485387/',
'https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/backend/public/notification/view/id/485256/',
'https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/backend/public/notification/view/id/487113/',
'https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/backend/public/notification/view/id/486733/',
'https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/backend/public/notification/view/id/486937/',
'https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/backend/public/notification/view/id/486946/',
'https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/backend/public/notification/view/id/485444/',
'https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/backend/public/notification/view/id/487258/',
'https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/backend/public/notification/view/id/487011/',
'https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/backend/public/notification/view/id/487254/']

MAX_THREADS = 30

Data_Source = "RASFF"
Product_Category = []
Date = []
Product_name = []
Reference = []

def scrape(links):
    data = requests.get(links).json()
    Product_Category.append(data["product"]["productCategory"]["description"])
    Date.append(data["ecValidationDate"])
    Product_name.append(data["product"]["description"])
    Reference.append(data["reference"])

        
def download_data(links_json):
    threads = min(MAX_THREADS, len(links_json))

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as executor:
       executor.map(scrape, links_json)

def main(new_links):
    t0 = time.time()
    download_data(new_links)
    t1 = time.time()
    print(f"{t1-t0} seconds to crawl {len(new_links)} in total.")

main(links_json)
```

When I try to run the main function, it is very inconsistent. Also right now there are only 12 links to scrape but as the links increase the data that should be extracted in the list also decreases. For instance: if there are about 200 links, there should be 200 values in the `Product_category` list but there are sometimes 100, 67 etc., meaning it is very inconsistent. I am not sure if I am missing something. I have even tried adding the `time.sleep(0.25)` in the scrape function but it does not work. I don't know how I can provide a list of 500 - 1000 links here.

Comment: The threads share the same process and hence memory, could be that inconsistency derives from concurrently appending data to that list?

Comment: Then what could be the use of using concurreny feature if we are not able to store the data that we are extracting, because if we are concurrently crawling these links then we should also be able to store the data somehow. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Concurrency feature allows to split a task across different threads/processes. If you want to share a data structure amongst different parallel tasks, that data structure should be concurrent proof.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so what can be a solution here using a different data structure or something else, because the final task is just to append the data collected.

Comment: Yes exactly the DS should be able to handle concurrent operation, I know `multiprocessing. Manager` allows this for multiprocessing, not sure if it's also good for multithreading

Comment: Your code is unlikely to produce expected results due to the threaded access to lists such as Product_Category which is inherently not thread-safe. You'd need to do some more elaborate coding to implement some kind of locking to ensure that there's no possibility of concurrent access to these lists

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how one could do this using the threading module:-

```
import requests
import threading

Product_Category = []
Date = []
Product_name = []
Reference = []
AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_5_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.2 Safari/605.1.15'
BASEURL = 'https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/backend/public/notification/view/id/'
LOCK = threading.Lock()

headers = {'User-Agent': AGENT}
links = ['485387',
         '485256',
         '487113',
         '486733',
         '486937',
         '486946',
         '485444',
         '487258',
         '487011',
         '487254']


def scrape(session, link):
    response = session.get(f'{BASEURL}{link}/', headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
    json = response.json()
    try:
        LOCK.acquire()
        Product_Category.append(
            json["product"]["productCategory"]["description"])
        Date.append(json["ecValidationDate"])
        Product_name.append(json["product"]["description"])
        Reference.append(json["reference"])
    finally:
        LOCK.release()


def main():
    with requests.Session() as session:
        ta = []
        for link in links:
            t = threading.Thread(target=scrape, args=(session, link))
            ta.append(t)
            t.start()
        for t in ta:
            t.join()
        print(Product_Category)
        print(Date)
        print(Product_name)
        print(Reference)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you @Andy for the answer, can you please explain a bit more about how the lock in threading works and also why do you use an agent here?

Comment: I pass a User-Agent header out of habit. Some URLs are inaccessible without it - i.e. you'll get HTTP 404. If you invoke the URL from a browser, then the browser will add the User-Agent automatically. You can read about threading and lock here:- https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html